# What's the best strategy for creating a web interface for a python application?

Tags: python, user-interface

I've created a simple gstreamer-based python audio application with a GTK+ GUI for picking and playing a webstream from a XML list. Then I connected my PC speakers output to the input of an old stereo receiver with large loudspeakers and presto, I have a pretty good sound system that is heard over most of my home.

Now I'd like to add a web user-interface to remote control the application from a room other than the one with the computer but so far all my attempts have been fruitless.

In particular I wonder if it is possible to create a sort of socket with signals like those of GTK GUIs to run methods that change gstreamer parameters.

Or is there a more realistic/feasible strategy?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The way I would do it... Create an `xmlrpc` function that controls the relevant controls on your GTK app; host that on the same server as your GTK app.  FYI, `web2py` is pretty good at `xmlrpc` services.  Create another web client that sends commands to the `xmlrpc` service; use anything you like to create this.  Direct manipulation of your GTK app from a web client sounds complicated to me.  My answer assumes you have some web development experience

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/), a very simple micro web-framework.

> Bottle is a fast, simple and lightweight WSGI micro web-framework for Python. It is distributed as a single file module and has no dependencies other than the Python Standard Library.

Hello world:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/hello/:name')
def index(name='World'):
    return '<b>Hello %s!</b>' % name

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: Hi Charlax, tks for introducing me to Bottle. It does exactly what I want however I can access the server only from the same machine where it is running. When I try from another computer on the same network I get a cannot access the host at... kind of error. This is consistent with the fact that when probed from the same host port 8080 seems open but from another machine the network scanner says the port is closed. It's probably a network configuration problem but I wonder if Bottle could be causing it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you serving on `0.0.0.0`? If you are using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` it will be available only locally. Have a look at http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#deployment

Comment: How foolish of me! Thanks again Charlax! It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and easiest way would probably be using [cgi-scripts](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/cgi.html?highlight=cgi#module-cgi). If you want  a more sophisticated approach you could consider using a webframework like django, turbogears or the likes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using one of the lighter-weight pure-Python web server options and either write a stand-alone WSGI application or use a micro-framework.

Gevent would be a good option: http://www.gevent.org/servers.html

Here is a sample implementation of a WSGI application using Gevent:
https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/src/tip/examples/wsgiserver.py#cl-4

For a micro-framework, I'd suggest using Flask.

Comment: Hi Restless Head! Thanks for yr answer. I hope to experiment with those in the future!